# Control <asp:UpdatePanel> not working properly

Tags: webforms

I have an `<asp:UpdatePanel>` on a page, but it doesn't work correctly. Namely: it works only 1 time, while third-party elements appear on the page.
Here is the code:

```
<div class="field-section-row" style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0">
    <div class="field-section">
        <asp:Label ID="lName" runat="server" Text="#Name#" meta:resourcekey="lName" CssClass="field-label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbName" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" xStringMaxLength="180" OnTextChanged="tbName_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" MaxLength="180"></asp:TextBox>
..........
</div>

<div class="field-section-row" style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upProductVariations" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <iLightSite:ProductVariations ID="productVariations" runat="server"></iLightSite:ProductVariations>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tbName" EventName="TextChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

As you can understand, when changing the value in the `tbName` input field, the `<iLightSite: ProductVariations>` control is automatically updated.
But there is a problem. The update occurs only 1 time, while third-party elements appear on the page:
[image: showing error]

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to use the UpdatePanel in different places, search in Google and ChatGPT, but alas, an error just appears as in the screenshot and that's it.

Comment: Start by removing the UpdatePanel and verify the form works as intended in all cases.  Then add the update panel and be sure you understand the UpdatePanel properties you set completely.  When things happen only once it's usually due to the dynamic nature of the panel, specifically controls not being reloaded after postback

Comment: Also it would be helpful to see the complete error message as the portion shown is just informative and not the actual error.

Comment: Everything works fine without the UpdatePanel. But as soon as I add it, everything breaks. There is no exception, the logger does not show anything, debugging too.

Comment: Then what are the errors highlighted in your post?

Comment: the browser dev tools should show an error. (often however, they don't, since you NOT running the required code after the update panel renders). However, see my post below, the issue is that the page "on ready" event that you use to setup the client side control(s) does not run after a update panel. So you have to add code to run the setup after "page load" event, and THEN ALSO run the same code after the update panel completes it's round trip. The update panel when returned to the browser does not trigger nor run the page on-ready event. See the solution below on how to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The hint here is the third party add-ins, or that of how most JavaScript add-ins work.

And that answer of how such most JavaScript libraries work, they let the whole page render, and then in most cases the page "on ready" then runs some JS code to load/setup/configure that control.

So, on first page load, the update panel really does not come into play, and it loads with all of the rest of the content on the page.

However, since the whole idea of the update panel is to not have full page post back, when you post back ONLY the update panel, then your third party JS code does not run again on page ready, since the page ready JS code does not re-run. After all, the idea here is to not have that full page post-back.

So, after the update panel is posted, then code behind (server side) runs. You are of course limited to only updating controls inside of that panel. Then just like a whole page "post-back and return" (the so-called round trip), then the updated content comes back to the client side. And just like the full-page post back, if you have control(s) inside that are based on some JS library, then the page on-ready does not trigger, and thus the JS code required to maintain, update, manage, and set up the third party control does not run again as required.

Let's show an example. For this example, let's use the "justGauge" example. This is a really nice third party gauge control.

So, we will enter a value in a text box - trigger the update panel.

So, we have this markup:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.4/raphael-min.js">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/justgage/1.2.9/justgage.min.js">
    </script>


    <div style="padding:35px">
        Enter Guage value:
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"
            OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"
            AutoPostBack="true"
            >
        </asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <h3>Update panel results</h3>

                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server"
                    value="5"
                    ClientIDMode="Static"
                    />
                 <div id="gauge0" style="width:130px;">
                 </div>

            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger 
                    ControlID="TextBox1" EventName="TextChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>


    </div>

    <script>
        var myGauge0;

        window.onload = function () {
            SetupGauge()
        }

        function SetupGauge() {
            console.log("Start setup")
            var gValue = $('#HiddenField1').val()

            myGauge0 = new JustGage({
                id: "gauge0",
                value: gValue,
                min: 0,
                max: 10,
                label: "Files Uploaded",
                showInnerShadow: true,
                shadowOpacity: 2,
                shadowSize: 5,
                startAnimationTime: 2000,
                startAnimationType: ">",
                refreshAnimationTime: 3000,
                refreshAnimationType: "bounce",
                donut: true,
                counter: true,
                relativeGaugeSize: true,
                guageColor: "#0094ff",
                levelColors: [
                    "#00fff6",
                    "#ff00fc",
                    "#1200ff"
                ]
            });
        }

    </script>
```

So, with that complex third party add-in (justGauge), then the page load client side has to trigger.

When we run the above, we get this:

[image]

Of course, the issue is that complex JS library has to re-run after our update panel post back. So the above example does not work.

Remember, an update panel does not actually prevent a post-back, but in fact posts part of the page, and it still does a "standard" round trip. That means that after the update panel code behind runs (and EVEN the page load event of that page ALWAYS runs with an update panel post-back), then the markup comes back down, but of course the JS gauge control does not have view state etc.

So, after the page updates, then that JS code needs to re-run (on page ready).

However, since we not doing a full-page post-back, then the required "on page ready" JS code does not re-run.

So, you can add some JS code to re-run code after the update panel completed its round trip.

So, this code can be added:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(SetupGauge);
```

So, now our script code becomes this:

```
    <script>
        var myGauge0;

        window.onload = function () {
            SetupGauge()
        }

        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(SetupGauge);

        function SetupGauge() {
            console.log("Start setup")
            var gValue = $('#HiddenField1').val()

            myGauge0 = new JustGage({
                id: "gauge0",
                value: gValue,
                min: 0,
                max: 10,
                label: "Files Uploaded",
                showInnerShadow: true,
                shadowOpacity: 2,
                shadowSize: 5,
                startAnimationTime: 2000,
                startAnimationType: ">",
                refreshAnimationTime: 3000,
                refreshAnimationType: "bounce",
                donut: true,
                counter: true,
                relativeGaugeSize: true,
                gaugeColor: "#0094ff",
                levelColors: [
                    "#00fff6",
                    "#ff00fc",
                    "#1200ff"
                ]
            });
        }

    </script>
```

And now our third party add-in works, since after the update panel runs, we call the same code as the "page on ready" that's required for this to work.

We now see/get this:

[image]

Comment: Albert: I can't speak for moderators, but it is my experience they will always side with editors where there are demonstrable improvements in an edit. Please leave them be.

Comment: I think I have reached to you in comments to explain why your material needs more than the average amount of editing. The way to improve that is to not keep making those errors. Do please respond when contacted by editors here - mutual editing is built into the content creation model, by design.

Comment: I think you have improved in several regards, but the contraction "let's" (meaning "let us") appears to be a daily stumbling block. Unfortunately English spell-checkers won't find it, because "lets" is a valid word (with a different meaning).

Comment: I'll reach out to you via chat when I have a bit more time.

Answer (score 0):

Friends, thank you all for your help. The problem turned out to be how the control located in the UpdatePanel works.
**I used RadAjaxManager instead of UpdatePanel and it worked.**